# Laravel 4 and twig upload file

Tags: php, laravel-4, upload

Trying to upload a file with this form...

```
{{ form_model(video, {'url': 'video/subtitle', 'files': 'true'}) }}
  {{ form_hidden('id') }}
  {{ form_file('name', '',  {class: 'form-control'}) }}
  {{ form_submit('ADD', {class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'}) }}
{{form_close()}}
```

**My Controller for the form URI**

```
public function postSubtitle() {
  $video = Video::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->find(Input::all('id')); 
  $typ = Input::all(); 
  print_r($typ); print_r(Input::file('name'));
}
```

This only returned: `Array ();`

Comment: Lets see your controller function for URI `video/subtitle`

Comment: `public function postSubtitle()
 {
  $video = Video::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->find(Input::all('id'));
  $typ = Input::all();
  print_r($typ);
  print_r(Input::file('name'));`

Comment: what is the difference between the Auth::id() and the form input ID?  Are they usually the same values?

Comment: it does not matter, I don't know, why return Array ();

Comment: This doesn't look like laravel anyway.  Besides your controller isn't returning anything to anywhere. I've never seen Laravel syntax like that either.

Comment: Can you update your question with the generated HTML of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your form should look like this

```
{{ Form::model(<VIDEO MODEL HERE>, ['url' => 'video/subtitle', 'files' => true]) }}
  {{ Form::file('name', ['class' => 'form-control'] }}
  {{ Form::submit('ADD', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'] }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And your controller should look like this

```
public function postSubtitle() { 
  $fileName = Input::file('name')->getClientOriginalName();
  return View::make('<SOME VIEW>')->withFile($fileName);
}
```

Comment: I use twigbridge so your answer does not help me

Comment: You should be using laravel since it comes with all of these tools.  And your already using laravel.  Stop complicating things

Comment: The situation will force me to do this with twigbride.